# generate python docstring template using current argument list

Tags: python, vim, docstring

I have a python package to release soon, so now I begin to slowly add docstrings to the files using vim. So for a func like

```
def foo(x, y, z=None, **kwargs):
```

I have to manually type the following repetitively for a whole day

```
""" foo does this stuff.

Parameters
----------
x: 
y:
z: optional
kwargs:

Returns
-------

"""
```

Is there a way to dynamically generate this template docstring by defining some vim macros (which I know nothing of, so a suggestion for how to start would be great as well). Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author of `vim-pydocstring` has kindly added the compatibility with Numpy-style docstrings to the package, which now seems to be the best answer to this question.

You can pull/download the vim plugin from [here](https://github.com/heavenshell/vim-pydocstring)

Answer (score 2):

Repeating the function name and arguments usually isn't the big deal (and insert-mode completion helps here); rather, you want a consistent skeleton where you just have to insert the variable information at the right places.

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets. With some advanced engines, you may even get extraction of the function and argument names itself.

Comment: found this, https://github.com/heavenshell/vim-pydocstring but still haven't figured out how to change the template file to achieve numpy style docstring yet.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are just normal actions recorded in a register and played back without delay.

One possible strategy would be to:

1. start recording,
2. duplicate that line above itself,
3. do all the needed manipulations,
4. stop recording,
5. play that macro back for every `def` line.

It would look like that:

```
qq
yyP
(all your text manipulations)
q
:g/def /normal! @q
```